# Is there a way to read a local JSON array in ES6?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

*Hi to whoever may read this! Would like to thank in advance any help or direction towards further research into this topic as I'm not sure I fully understand the logic.*

I'm creating a react app which uses a button component and gets it's props from an external but local JSON array made up of names. For instance:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as buttonNames from '/localdirectory/buttonNames.json';

class Buttons extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {buttonNames.map((buttonName, i) => {
                return <button>{buttonName}</button>
            }}
        );
    }
}
```

And the JSON array looks like this:

```
[
"10A",
"10B",
"10C",
"10D",
"10E",
"10F"
]
```

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do however the expected result from my perspective is that the mapping function should iterate through the JSON array and assign each to the `buttonName` variable which would then be used to create 6 different buttons with the innerHTML filled by the content of the array item.

**However the program throws an error which states that `map` is not exported from the JSON array, why would it need to be in the first place? Shouldn't the program be simply importing it and treating it as a standard array which has built-in JS methods such as `map` and `forEach`**

I've tried working with the file as a CSV and importing using D3, however that returns a promise which I'd prefer not to be the case as I'm using it load the UI and the file which contains the `buttonNames` isn't particularly large. Using `JSON.parse()` also does not work as the program states that the target is already an object.

Appreciate and open to any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried importing the JSON file with `import buttonNames from '/localdirectory/buttonNames.json';`

Comment: Hello, are you exporting that array?? I can't see anywhere you are exporting it.

Comment: The import seems to be working fine from what I can see, console.logging the type and the imported array displays what I want but I will try exporting it explicitly. @Mwibutsa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It's about your import statement.

while handling JSON files in js, it's been turned into a js that export data.

```json
[1,2,3]
```

with

```js
import data from "./data.json"
console.log(data) // [1,2,3]
```

with

```js
import * as data from "./data.json"
console.log(data) // {0:1,1:2,2:3, default:[1,2,3]}
```

as it's been treated as ES module, you import an object instead of the array itself, so the map function will be undefined, as it's just a plain object.

---

### Here's why

Webpack load JSON with [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader), which is officially supported so that you won't need to configure yourself, and the json-loader will handle JSON files by stringify it and concat with `module.exports=`, [source code here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader/blob/master/index.js#L10),
so the JSON will be in js like

```js
module.exports = [0,1,2]
```

and as the module. exports object itself will be imported as `default` export in an ESM file, and all objects fields will be exported as others, so you will get an ESM object while doing `import * as data from "./data.json"`

Of cause, if you are using a different JSON loader the value will be different, but the error is what you meet.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood what the `import * as` syntax was actually doing and I thought that I needed an export statement in the JSON in order for this to work without it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, JSON array should be treated as native in JS. It is. You don't have to change your JSON. Problem is the `import *` syntax, do not use it. Instead:

```js
     import buttonNames from '/localdirectory/buttonNames.json';
```

Which will be imported smoothly by Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JSON does not Support Arrays. Try:

```
{
  0: "10A",
  1: "10B",
  2: "10C",
  3: "10D",
  4: "10E",
  5: "10F"
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import buttonNames from '/localdirectory/buttonNames.json';

class Buttons extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {Object.values(buttonNames).map((buttonName, i) => {
                return <button>{buttonName}</button>
            }}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, JSON couldn't parse it due a syntax error from an `unexpected number at position 6`. Thanks all the same however

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/export-import-array-mpgw4)

**Json file**

```js
{
  "data": ["10A", "10B", "10C", "10D", "10E", "10F"]
}
```

**JSX**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { data } from "./myJson.json";

export default function App() {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {data.map(d => (
        <p>{d}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I try this the program fails to compile stating that the `e` in `export` is an unexpected token? This seems to be the case in my experience when I try to export from a JSON file. Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey, how does your json file looks, please make sure you are not exporting from that, it should be simple json file